# Copy sheet with excel vba

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to copy one sheet from Workbook A to newly added Workbook B.
The problem I have is that it does not keep the PageSetup. The new workbook with the copied sheet doesnt fit on one page as the original source does.
I have tried to research this but cant determine if I need to copy all the attributes in the PageSetup or if it should just work when copying the whole sheet.
This is my code so far:

```
     Public Sub makeCopies(ByVal seller As String)
        Dim thisWB As Workbook
        Dim newWB As Workbook
        Set thisWB = ActiveWorkbook

        Set newWB = Workbooks.Add
        On Error GoTo ErrorHandler:
        thisWB.Sheets(1).Copy Before:=newWB.Sheets(1)
        newWB.Activate

        newWB.SaveAs fileName:=seller & ".xlsx"
        newWB.Close
        thisWB.Activate
        Exit Sub

    ErrorHandler:
        MsgBox "Error" & Err.Number & Err.Description
        newWB.Close
    End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

It is a bit unclear as to exactly **what** [Worksheet.PageSetup](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.tools.excel.worksheet.pagesetup.aspx) property or properties are not being carried across. In the following procedure, modified slightly so that orphaned, blank worksheets are not included in the new workbook, the '× wide by × tall' property as well as 'rows to repeat at top' were carried across to the new worksheet/workbook faithfully.

```
Sub main()
    makeCopies "makeCopies"
End Sub

Public Sub makeCopies(ByVal seller As String)
   Dim thisWB As Workbook
   Dim newWB As Workbook
   Set thisWB = ActiveWorkbook

   On Error GoTo ErrorHandler:
   thisWB.Sheets(1).Copy
   Set newWB = ActiveWorkbook

   newWB.SaveAs Filename:=Environ("TEMP") & Chr(92) & seller & ".xlsx"
   newWB.Close
   thisWB.Activate
   Exit Sub

ErrorHandler:
   MsgBox "Error" & Err.Number & Err.Description
   newWB.Close
End Sub
```

Copying a worksheet to 'no destination' creates a new workbook with that workbook holding the [ActiveWorkbook property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff821871.aspx). The only worksheet will be a direct copy of the original which seems more desirable unless you need 1-3 blank worksheets in the new workbook for some reason.